# How to detect memory leak using gTest in C++ on Linux platform

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, googletest

I am new to gTest. I have to load of functions for which I already have the gTest unit test cases.

I want to add functionality to detect memory leaks in my orginal functions inside the unit test cases already exist.

Is there a way to perform this?

Regards,
Mahendra

Answer (score 1):

Googletest is not the sort of a tool for detecting memory leaks. Unit-testing tests the run-time functionality of software elements. Detecting memory leaks in a compiled application calls for dynamic analysis of its execution at binary level in conjunction with debugging information generated by the compiler and linker.

There are tools for detecting memory leaks, to be used independently of your unit-testing framework. For Linux, a commonplace choice is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It will be provided in the package repositories of your distro and you will be able to install it with your package manager. If you use an IDE it may well support Valgrind integration
via a plugin or other means.